# Android XPath HTML parsing like TFHpple (I got a 10-line Obj-C implementation working, can't translate)

Tags: android, xml, xpath, html-parsing

2 days ago I wrote this objective-c code to extract text from a website which works exactly as intended. Now I have no idea how to implement this for Android. It's just really weird with Android,

- some XPath code that everyone posts is incompatible with HTML files (only accepts standard-XML)
- JSoup (which can deal with HTML) can't into Xpath
- all in all I am walking in circles right now.

Basically, what I need is to get the elements around `//h2/a` from a html file at a specific URL. **Please take a look at my obj-c implementation that I wrote, it's literally 10 lines of working code but I can't figure out a way to do the same in Android.**

```
-(void)loadTutorials:(NSString*)startURLS {

NSURL *tutorialsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:startURLS];
NSData *tutorialsHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tutorialsUrl];
TFHpple *tutorialsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:tutorialsHtmlData];

NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//h2/a";
NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];

NSString *podcastTitles[99];

int jjj=0;
for (NSString *string in tutorialsNodes) {
    podcastTitles[jjj]=[[[tutorialsNodes[jjj] firstChild] content] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    NSLog(@"%@",podcastTitles[jjj]); //WORKING PERFECTLY FINE
    jjj++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, key was to stick to XPathFactory BUT feeding it a `HTMLCleaner`-cleaned HTML. Unfortunately I can't find the SO answer that got me on track, so no credit today but hopefully I will stumble across it again.

Idk how many of these lines are necessary and I won't ever clean this code but this block now works for me.

```
HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
                CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();
                props.setAllowHtmlInsideAttributes(true);
                props.setAllowMultiWordAttributes(true);
                props.setRecognizeUnicodeChars(true);
                props.setOmitComments(true);


                TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner().clean(
                        websiteContent);
                org.w3c.dom.Document doc = new DomSerializer(
                        new CleanerProperties()).createDOM(tagNode);

                XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
                NodeList titleNodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//h2/a",
                        doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                System.out.println("iii"+titleNodes);

                for(int i=0; i<titleNodes.getLength();i++){
                    System.out.println("t t t"+titleNodes.item(i).getTextContent()); //WORKING
                }
```